# Android N crashes in TextAppearanceSpan

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-7.0-nougat

Since upgrading my Nexus 5X to Android N, I have the following crash when using EditText:

```
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:528)
       at android.text.style.TextAppearanceSpan.<init>(TextAppearanceSpan.java:65)
       at android.text.style.TextAppearanceSpan.<init>(TextAppearanceSpan.java:45)
       at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.setUp(Editor.java:3316)
       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3016)
       at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3309)
       at android.widget.Editor.replace(Editor.java:356)
       at android.widget.Editor$3.run(Editor.java:2129)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

It happens when clicking on an EditText that has some text already. I am assuming it is the auto-correct popup or something similar.

My app uses support libs 24.2.0 and Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Edit: It works fine if I add `android:colorAccent` in addition to just `colorAccent` in my theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mainBrandColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/mainBrandDarkerColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/mainBrandColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/mainBrandColor</item>
</style>
```

But this shouldn't be needed as I inherit from Theme.AppCompat.

I made a small app that showcases the problem:

https://github.com/martinbonnin/TextAppearanceSpanCrash/blob/master/app/src/main/java/mbonnin/com/textappearancescancrash/MainActivity.java

Comment: If you can create a sample app that reproduces the problem, [file an issue](http://b.android.com).

Comment: @CommonsWare I could finally reproduce. It seems to be linked to creating a WebView after an AppCompatEditText. Issue filed there: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221504.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? It still happens on 25.3.1

Comment: @mbonnin fixed yet?

Comment: @sanjeev not sure, it's been a long time I haven't checked

Answer (score 8):

In the stack trace there was a reference to SuggestionsPopupWindow that made me think of disabling suggestions for EditText.

I used the following code as a workaround:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        if ((editText.getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS) != InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS) {
            editText.setInputType(editText.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        }
    }
```

We can also set inputType in XML, but the above code allows us to add TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS to existent input type.

Comment: Yea, I did that for the time being. I do not really consider this a proper fix though.

Comment: I'm seeing this in Android M, N, and O. It doesn't appear to be OS versions specific.

Comment: Kitkat here.. Has problems on that too.. Anyone got an idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your Edit text view
android:textAppearance="@color/"
like this:

```
<EditText 
      android:textAppearance="@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark"
      ...
/>
```

"@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark" (built in) :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_disabled_material_dark"/>
    <item android:color="@color/bright_foreground_material_dark"/>
</selector>
```

it works for me

Comment: I don't know why this works, but it seems setting TextAppearance works in Android 10 w/Android X (if you put it in the autosuggested TextView used with the ArrayAdapter.)  You can set it to a custom @color, not just this abc_ value.  It eliminates the crash for me!

Answer (score 2):

Updating the support library to 25.0.0 or higher fixes this issue