# how to apply TextInputLayout style and errorTextAppearance style both

Tags: android, textinputlayout

I am trying to implement both styles in text input but it's not working
while applying `errorTextAppearance` style I am getting an error.

```
08-20 09:55:27.959 5081-5081/com.rayvatapps.ctvforme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rayvatapps.ctvforme, PID: 5081
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:469)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:892)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:818)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:87)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:83)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:79)
    at android.support.design.widget.IndicatorViewController.setErrorEnabled(IndicatorViewController.java:422)
    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(TextInputLayout.java:938)
    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(TextInputLayout.java:1055)
    at com.rayvatapps.ctvforme.FormActivity.validateEmail(FormActivity.java:237)
    at com.rayvatapps.ctvforme.FormActivity.access$600(FormActivity.java:53)
    at com.rayvatapps.ctvforme.FormActivity$MyTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(FormActivity.java:326)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9375)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:11917)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1262)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:574)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:504)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:502)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:843)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:616)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:396)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/edname"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:hint="@string/full_name"
             android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
             android:inputType="" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
 if (edName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            tilName.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
            requestFocus(edName);
            return false;
 } else 
 {
           tilName.setErrorEnabled(false);
 }
```

**STYLE**

```
<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#4DFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_20sdp</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#4DFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/error_appearance</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Did you check this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41727729/5180017)?

Comment: In TectInputlayout use this => style="@style/TextLabel"

Comment: I check this but when I apply only one style it's working

Comment: already using android:theme="@style/TextLabel"

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413575/how-to-write-style-to-error-text-of-edittext-in-android

Comment: try  => parent="@android:style/TextAppearance" in style because it's working for me

Comment: getting error: attribute 'android:parent' not found.

Comment: can you please post a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after changing TextLabel `theme` parent to Widget.Design.TextInputLayout it's working now

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#4DFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_20sdp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#4DFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```