# Moving from SDK 21 to SDK 28

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I completed this move and worked out most of the kinks however there is one problem I've not been able to solve. Did a search and tried to make sense of the results, tried a few things but still no progress. The problem seems to be related to the Styles/Themes in the app.

Stack trace

```
Process: net.myapp.app.debug, PID: 14927
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.myapp.app.debug/net.myapp.app.ui.SplashSreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2654)
    at net.shopayard.app.ui.SplashSreenActivity.onCreate(SplashSreenActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:538)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:904)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:818)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:814)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2654) 
    at net.myapp.app.ui.SplashSreenActivity.onCreate(SplashSreenActivity.java:42) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

build.grade (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('C:/Users/myapp/.android/debug.keystore')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 22
        versionName '3.0.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:2.3.0'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile(name: 'analyticslibrary', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
}
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/switch_thumb_normal</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ToolbarThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/SubTitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/SubTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SubTitleTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SpinnerButton">
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_button_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>
    <style name="EditTextRectangleStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/black_rectangle</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>
    <style name="EditTextStyle">
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_bg</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>
    <style name="EditTextNoMarginsStyle">
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_bg</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>
    <style name="FormLabelClickable" parent="FormLabelStyle">
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/clickable_black_text</item>
    </style>
    <style name="FormLabelStyle">
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>
    <style name="StandardSwitch" parent="FormLabelStyle" >
        <item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/switch_text_dark_gray</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SwitchLabelStyle">
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/content_margin_normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomTabPageIndicator">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="pstsTextAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFAAAAAA</item>
        <item name="pstsIndicatorColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="pstsDividerColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="pstsShouldExpand">true</item>
        <item name="pstsIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
        <item name="pstsTabPaddingLeftRight">1dp</item>
        <item name="pstsUnderlineColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="pstsUnderlineHeight">0dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="dialog_popup_slideout">
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_dialog</item>
    </style>
    <style name="dialog_slidein_slideout">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_dialog</item>
    </style>
    <style name="dialog_slidein_left_slideout">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_dialog</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ButtonBarButton" />
    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>
    <style name="FullscreenTheme.NoActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NumberPickerDialog" parent="DialogCenteredTitle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">280dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DialogCenteredTitle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CenteredTitle</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CenteredTitle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RedRectangularButton" parent="BlueRectangularButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_rectangle_button_bg_selector</item>
    </style>
    <style name="BlueRectangularButton">
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/rectangular_button_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/rectangular_button_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_rectangle_button_bg_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ImageViewAttachment">
        <item name="android:width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/select_image_min_height</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/dashed_rectangle_selector</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">0.25</item>
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/symbol_camera</item>
        <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/splash_background"
    tools:context="net.myapp.app.ui.SplashSreenActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutError"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/error_maintenance"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_margin_normal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRetry"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/retry"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button_blue_selector"/>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBarRetry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">myapp</string>
    <string name="ic_action_search">Search</string>
    <string name="ic_action_profile">Profile</string>
    <string name="ic_action_refresh">Refresh</string>
    <string name="action_call">Call</string>
    <string name="action_email">Email</string>
    <string name="action_share">Share</string>
    <string name="action_location">Location</string>
    <string name="action_report">Report</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
    <string name="register_below">Register below to receive deals and promotions from local businesses.</string>
    <string name="gender">Gender</string>
    <string name="birth_year">Year of birth</string>
    <string name="island">Island</string>
    <string name="button_done">Done</string>
    <string name="button_ok">OK</string>
    <string name="loading">Loading...</string>
    <string name="title_activity_profile">Profile</string>
    <string name="title_activity_deals_details">DealsDetailsActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_fullscreen_image">FullscreenImageActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_classified_details">ClassifiedDetailsActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_splash_sreen">SplashSreenActivity</string>

    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <string name="retry">Retry</string>
    <string name="retry_failed">Retry failed</string>
    <string name="error_maintenance">The servers are currently undergoing maintenance, please try again in a few minutes.</string>
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary_color_clicked">#0071a8</color>
    <color name="primary_color">#004A77</color>
    <color name="primary_color_dark">#004368</color>
    <color name="switch_thumb_normal">#004A77</color>
    <color name="switch_text_dark_gray">#464646</color>
    <color name="accent">#80A4BB</color>
    <color name="orange">#EA5C04</color>
    <color name="dark_red">#A00809</color>
    <color name="red_divider">#A91F20</color>
    <color name="line_light_gray">#D9D9D9</color>
    <color name="text_blue">#004A77</color>
    <color name="text_white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="text_gray">#969696</color>
    <color name="text_content_dark">#333</color>
    <color name="text_dark_red">#980000</color>
    <color name="tab_text_inactive">#98b6c8</color>
    <color name="text_orange">#E74700</color>
    <color name="text_black">#111111</color>
    <color name="text_black_focused">#888888</color>
    <color name="button_blue">#004A77</color>
    <color name="button_blue_focused">#0075BA</color>
    <color name="menu_list_divider">#9DD0F5</color>
    <color name="menu_selected_item_background">#D6EDFF</color>
    <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
    <color name="search_background">#A7D9FE</color>
    <color name="splash_background">#A6D8FD</color>
    <color name="darken_filter_color">#22000000</color>
    <color name="classified_id_background">#DDDDDD</color>
    <color name="red_button">#A00809</color>
    <color name="red_button_focused">#f40809</color>
</resources>
```

The issue seems to be related to FullscreenTheme or FullscreenTheme.NoActionBar since I've been testing different approaches and have gotten different stack traces when changing these. However the code above was all running fine in SDK 21. I have a feeling a trained eye would see the issue instantly but I'm not a daily programmer regrettably.

Comment: have you tried creating a separate xml and using it as your layout?

Comment: No answer here, but try searching for the id ["android 0x101009b"](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+0x101009b&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab) and you will find similar problems discussed and, sometimes, fixed like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727729/fatal-exception-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-failed-to-resolve-attr).

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says that it failed finding @string/error_maintenance.
Try to `clean project` and to see if it has have the String resource named error_maintenance.

Plus, before, in my projects I was able to create a String resource with a dot like "error.maintenance" and calling it using `@string/error_maintenance`.
Since api 28 I had to remove every dots in my strings.xml

Comment: I tried just hard coding the text strings, but compilation still failed with the same message.

Comment: @vonStack if you remove the TextView, does it work? If it bugs, it it not the same error message

Comment: If I comment out the TextView and the Button then it runs, why would this stop working by just going from SDK 21 -> 28 :/

Comment: Please edit your post and add the strings.xml file and colors.xml. if you can also give the error log when you comment only the TextView, it would be helpful

Comment: Added the requested files as above.