# How to find id of attribute with error message

Tags: android, android-layout

The project I work with has a lot of customization and a lot of components with attributes from different internal libraries. I have to create a custom dialog and set a specific theme on it. I can't pinpoint which attributes are missing from the components used inside and fail to launch my dialog.

I've got this error :

```
Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0401c8 a=7}
```

Is it possible to find the exact attribute name from this error ? What does `t`, `d` and `a` means ?

Comment: I think you should check here https://stackoverflow.com/q/41727729/12660050

Comment: It did not help me, I already know that I miss attributes. I want to know which attributes are missing but the error do not say the names explicitly. I cannot just search for specific ids as comment says in : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67083167/4681367 because what I search are custom attributes from closed internal aar (not android attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message probably comes from [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/TypedValue.java;drc=master;l=540). Documentation for *TypedValue* is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue).

The type (t) is an attribute. The associated data (d) is `0x7f0401c8` which is the attribute id. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646113/6287910) is still a good place to understand the structure of the id. "a" is the asset cookie associated with the attribute which, I think, indicates the the resolved value will be a string.

You may be able to get the name of the resource with a call to [Resources#getResourceName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getResourceName(int)). If that fails, you can work back through the stack trace to where the attribute is being looked up to glean what is being sought. You could also set a break point at the line mentioned in the error message you posted and search back through the call stack. I assume that you have access to the source code which will aid you in the search.